# How to change selected value after clicked it and remove previous?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i have a `php` view and i want to change the

class after clicked

```
<ul>
  <li> <a href="<?=base_url()?>home"  id="home" onclick="select_class('home');" class="shortcut-dashboard" title="Home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?=base_url()?>message"  class="shortcut-messages" id='mesg' onclick="select_class('mesg');" title="Messages">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    function select_class(id){
        if(id=='mesg'){
            $('#'+id).addClass('current');
            $('#home').removeClass('current');
        }
        else{
            $('#home').addClass('current');
            $('#mesg').removeClass('current');
        }
    }
</script>
```

how can i select the selected value to make this visible and remove previous one

Comment: Not an answer but you should consider updating your jquery file, 1.7.2 is quite old now.

Comment: Jquery is working well in all my site its not jqury file problem. i m missing some technical point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing this problem but I just change the selected class and place it to

```
<a class='current'>
```

from css then it works for me try yourself then your problem will solve and also do this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#shortcuts li a').each(function(index) {
        if(this.href.trim() == window.location)
            $(this).addClass("current");
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.toggleClass()` instead.

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="example">
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>test 2</li>
</ul>

$('#example li').click(function(e){
    $('#example li').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/mRKC6/

Comment: it does not apply on anchor because when i clicked it open new page so it select by default 1st one class that is assigned to home

Comment: i am doing it on the behalf of anchor command because i want to go from one page to other

Comment: change the js to this to prevent the default action of the anchor

http://jsfiddle.net/mRKC6/1/

Comment: Seglespaan its work but i am facing problem that by doing this my page dont go to desired page mean anchor commend dont move page(href='message.php')

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mRKC6/1/ on this site it also not move to google after clicked

Comment: Ok perhaps I misunderstood the question? So when the link is clicked you want to go to that page, then when reaching that page you want to highlight the current page in the menu? Is this correct?

Comment: Ok in that case, if you want to do this using jquery then when the page loads use window.location.pathname to get the current path and then strip out what you don't want using split or substring untill your left with the id of the anchor tag, and apply a class of current to that.

Comment: can u tell me window.location.pathname  with little example?

Comment: I'd rather not publicly. And you don't have enough rep to open chat

Answer (score 0):

Please change js type

```
 <script type="application/javascript">
```

to

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
```